# python: using two columns of a dataframe with scipy linregress

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I am trying to use `linregress` (`scipy.stats`) with 2 columns of a dataframe  (both have 7 rows), but I always run into this message:

```
 slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err=linregress( sma5_slope[stocks],sma5_slope['counter'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_stats_mstats_common.py", line 93, in linregress
    ssxm, ssxym, ssyxm, ssym = np.cov(x, y, bias=1).flat
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 3044, in cov
    X = np.concatenate((X, y), axis=0)
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

I have a pandas dataframe `sma5` with only one data column and the index (= date).
I'm trying to calculate the slope of the last 7 rows, so I create a new df with the last 7 rows:

```
sma5_slope = sma5.iloc[-7:]
```

Adding a counter:

```
sma5_slope['counter'] = range(len(sma5_slope))
```

Then sma5_slope looks e.g. like this:

```
               TSLA  counter
2018-04-12  297.734        0
2018-04-13  297.942        1
2018-04-16  298.252        2
2018-04-17  294.850        3
2018-04-18  293.334        4
2018-04-19  294.534        5
2018-04-20  293.130        6
```

Then I'm passing the 2 columns of `sma5_slope` to `linregress`:

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err=linregress( sma5_slope['counter'], sma5_slope[stocks])
```

(I'm looping over a few elements, `stocks` is the current symbol.

Could you point out where my mistake is? :)
I thought both `X` and `Y` consist of 7 elements...?

Comment: Does `sma5_slope` has variable `stock` as a column name? Or this is a row value inside the column?

Comment: Yes, the column name refers to the variable "stock"                           
P.S.: sorry about my bad formatting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is indicating that your 2 Series have different lengths.

You can try:

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err=linregress( sma5_slope['counter'], sma5_slope['TSLA'])
```

You can further make sure by printing the following:

```
print(len(sma5_slope('counter'))
#should be 7
print(len(sma5_slope('TSLA'))
#should be 7
```

Comment: Thanks iDrwish! It's working now after I've changed the variable column name to a string as you have suggested. So something must be shaky with the column name and I'll look into this.

Comment: Consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if it met your inquiry.

Comment: Ah, the loop elements were enclosed by `['` and `']` Not very elegantly, I removed these characters `curr_symbol=str(stocks).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\'','')` and now I can use curr_symbol in the lingregress-call. Thanks!